# SpriteKit Texture Atlas not working

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, textures

So my issue is that the .atlas images are no longer being displayed. I have tried many ways to solve this, but the issue is that ever since I updated XCODE the regular way of using texture atlas has stopped working. My problem is that all my code is correct yet the images are showing up as unknown when I run the program.

My image files are set up as "Car.atlas" 
Is the file supposed to be set up in a different way by any chance?

Im sorry if this is vague, but any help would be great thanks!

Comment: check to make sure the files are  being included in the resources section of your build phase

Comment: Im sorry, how can I check that?

Comment: Also if they are not in the resources section, then what can I do to fix it?

Comment: click on the project settings, and go to build phases.  If they are not there, then add them

Comment: Thank you very much sir! You have saved me from a lot of headache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the project settings, and go to the build phases tab.

Check the resources section to verify that the files are included. If they are not there, then add them.